# Importer or converter for ClarisWorks cwk format?

Tags: conversion, import

I have several ClarisWorks documents (*.CWK) that I'd like to import into a more modern format like Microsoft Word or Open Office. It seems [Star Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarOffice) can apparently open cwk files, but the product is discontinued and cannot be downloaded any more. There has been a [feature request](http://openoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7906) to add a cwk importer to OpenOffice since 2002, so I doubt that OpenOffice will support cwk files any time soon.

Are there any utilities that can open a cwk file besides ClarisWorks itself?

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice will also do the job. http://www.libreoffice.org/ - opens them perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[MacText](http://www.macdisk.com/mactxten.php) can convert ClarisWorks. I don't believe StarOffice ever could, despite what people say. I have documented my own work attempting to reverse engineer the .cwk format [here](http://wiki.wirelust.com/x/index.php/Projects:Archiving:AppleWorks).

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: Link rot here....